# How to make QPushButton to remain in pressed state till the process completes?

Tags: qt

I have a button which when clicked will run back-end process for, say, 10 sec.
I would like to make the button in pressed state till the process completes and then the button be released. This is, so that the user knows when the process is complete. As an example:

```
QString ExButtonStyleSheet = "QPushButton{background-color:lightgreen;}\
                            QPushButton:hover{background-color:yellow;}\
                            QPushButton:pressed{background-color:green;}\
                            QPushButton:disabled{background-color:grey;}";
```

In the above case, once clicked the button goes to hover state (yellow) even when the process is running (GUI is also busy) and turns lightgreen once free.
But this is not very explicit to the user, unlike the pressed state.(Note the above stylesheet is just an example and in my actual styesheet the hover state color is only slightly different from the normal.)
I am looking for a solution where the button remains to look pressed and only to be released when the process is complete.

Answer (score 6):

You can theoretically use

```
QPushButton::setCheckable(true)
QPushButton::setDown(true) // Button is down
// Expensive task
QPushButton::setDown(false) // Button is released
```

**Freezing the GUI for 10 seconds is a very bad idea.**

You should use threads for your expensive tasks instead of blocking the GUI. Call `QPushButton::setDown(true)` and emit a signal to the thread which contains the code of the expensive task.

When the thread finishes the thread should call a slot in your MainWindow that contains `QPushButton::setDown(false)`. This way your GUI will be fully responsive during the time and you follow the good coding behaviours.

Comment: Thanks. Note: repaint() was needed after setDown(true) to work consistently. Regarding using thread, in my particular case, it is better that the GUI freezes than give user the GUI control during the transient time and  complicating the code.

Comment: Then you could lock the controls during the operation. The problem with freezing is that the OS will probably warn you that something bad is happening to the program, and will ask you to shut it. And for the users, it just seems like it crashed.

Comment: Why `setDown` rather than `setChecked`? When you use `setDown`, it is not going to make `isChecked` return true

Comment: @SomethingSomething because setDown is the correct solution for the question. setDown is for temporary visual effect and setChecked is a toggle button with signals.